Setup subnet with mixing static and auto IP container address assignment
Basically I have this setup:
networks:
  default:
    name: wgnet
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 172.20.0.0/24

services:

  image1:
    image: image_source
    container_name: image1
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.2

  image2:
    image: image_source
    container_name: image2




Sometimes when I bring up the services, it causes a IP conflict error message Error response from daemon: Address already in use. At the moment I'm evading this issue by depends_on: - image1 on the other container.
Although this is not ideal to me, as this causes a dependency nightmare with all my services.. Is there a method to alleviate this from just networking controls?
